# Adding new columns to a text file on matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab and I need some help. I want to re-use three columns from a txt file and add two extra ones created by me.

**My .txt file is:**

```
"Abel" 70 1.80 55 M
"Ana" 55 1.73 68 F
"Xavier" 65 1.82 61 M
"Rui" 80 1.79 23 M
```

**This is the code I wrote:**

```
[nome,peso,altura,idade,genero]=textread('imc.txt','%q%n%f%n%c')

for k=1:length(peso)

    imc(k)=peso(k)./(altura(k).^2)
end

for k=1:length(imc)

    if imc(k)>24.9
        imc_ok{k}='over'
    elseif imc(k)<18.5
        imc_ok{k}='under'
    else
        imc_ok{k}='ok'
    end
end

imc=imc';
imc_ok=(imc_ok)';

fid=fopen('imc.txt','wt');

for i=1:length(imc)
fprintf(fid,'%q,%n,%f,%f,%s',nome(i,1),peso(i,1),altura(i,1),imc(i,1),imc_ok{i})
   end
fclose(fid)
```

I would like to create a new text file with `nome`, `peso`, `altura`, `imc` and `imc_ok`, I've tried searching and replacing `(i,1)` for `{i}` but it didn't work.

```
"Abel" 70 1.80 21.6 ok
"Ana" 55 1.73 18.3 under 
"Xavier" 65 1.82 19.6 ok 
"Rui" 80 1.79 23 24.9 over
```

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of how you want the new text file to look, please. What are the extra rows? How do you intend to add them? How do you call your function?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't call your function `textread` as this is a built-in Matlab function.

Comment: I was actually using textread to read the .txt file, I wasn't creating a function. I already edited my question, thanks

Comment: So you actually want to replace the last 2 **columns**, not _rows_. May be you should edit your title to reflect that, because before your edit it was rather confusing.

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry!

Comment: @PauloMaia Ah, I read the word function that didn't exist. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major thing which was making the `fprintf` fail was your `%n` in the format specifier. In matlab use a `%d` instead.

slightly rewriting your last loop with a modified format specifier will produce the desired output:

```
%% // write new file
fileout = 'imc_out.txt' ;
fid=fopen(fileout,'wt');
for i=1:length(imc)
    fprintf(fid,'%s %d %3.2f %3.1f %s\n',nome{i},peso(i),altura(i),imc(i),imc_ok{i}) ;
end
fclose(fid)
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I don't quite understand why %3.2f is used, doesn't %f automatically convert it to the correct number of decimal places?

Comment: `%f` was working fine to convert the decimal number to string but they were having way too many digit to be easily readable. I used `%3.2` to have only 2 digits after the coma, as per your example. Look at the Matlab documentation about [format specifiers](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?refresh=true#inputarg_formatSpec), they explain the subtleties.