# Add new column with header to csv Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I have an csv file with column headers (strings) and data. I then want to add a new column with a specific header `'My new header'` and data is stored in a 100x1 double variable called `myNewData`. How I can add a new column with header `'My new header'` and values of the column be `myNewData`?

Comment: This is not that easy since if you open a csv file to append data using `fopen('myFile.csv','at')` you will append your data in new rows. I think to append a new column you will have to rewrite the file. So you use `fopen` and `textscan` on your existing file and then you will concatenate strings that you can write to a new file using `fprintf`. Maybe this might help:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783802/adding-new-columns-to-a-text-file-on-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this using tables in Matlab in just three lines of code as shown below:

```
table = readtable('myfile.csv','Delimiter',',');
table.class = newcol; %where class is the name of the header of the new column and newcol is a variable which has my new column data
writetable(table,'myfilenew.csv','Delimiter',',','QuoteStrings',false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by

1. Reading data and headers with `importdata`
2. Modifying the data and headers
3. Writing the data to a new (or the same) file

You can write your data either using [this awesome function](http://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29933-csv-with-column-headers) from the MATLAB file exchange, or you can do it manually via `fprintf` and `dlmwrite`

Here is a complete example:

```
% Write test data
filename = 'myfile01.csv';
fid = fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(fid,'col1,col2,col3\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n10,11,12');
fclose(fid);

% Define new column
myNewHeader = 'My new header';
myNewData = randi(9,[4,1]);

% Read test data and headers
filename = 'myfile01.csv';
delimiter = ',';
headerlinesIn = 1;
A = importdata(filename, delimiter, headerlinesIn);

% Append new colum to data
data_new = cat(2, A.data, myNewData);
colheaders_new = [A.colheaders, myNewHeader];
clear A

% Write the result to a new file (or the same)
filename_new = 'myfile01_new.csv';
fid = fopen(filename_new,'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s,', colheaders_new{1,1:end-1});
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', colheaders_new{1,end});
fclose(fid);
dlmwrite(filename_new, data_new, '-append', 'precision', '%u', 'delimiter', ',');

% Or, using the function from the File Exchange:
csvwrite_with_headers(filename_new, data_new, colheaders_new);
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I can get the last value of the selected column in `M = csvread('myfile.csv',1,33,[1,33,Inf,33])` ? As I'm reading a column first then processing, then I'm gonna use/test your code.

Comment: Do you mean `M(end)`?

Comment: no, like in this line of code I want to get the all the values of column 33 starting from row 1 till the end (number of rows in the csv file) there is something wrong with using `Inf` so I should replace it with something.

Comment: You would have to determine the number of lines in the file. See for example [this discussion](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81137-pre-determining-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file).

Comment: I tried your answer but it gives an error `Reference to non-existent field 'colheaders'.` in this line `colheaders_new = [A.colheaders, myNewHeader];` as A has only data and textdata no colheaders

Comment: Does the file have headers? If not, you can define them yourself.

Comment: Yes, the first row has my header names

Comment: See if the headers are in the field `A.textdata`

Comment: Yes, the headers are located in the first row of `A.textdata`

Comment: And I just found another problem, some of my columns holds text values in numbers so they are included in `A.textdata` not `A.data`

Comment: The .csv format is not designed for mixed data types. Read for example in the MATLAB documentation on `csvread` "The file must contain only numeric values". Consider using the [.xls](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) format.

Comment: but what you if my file had it such in my case? Thank you very much for trying to help me anyway, I really appreciate it, I learnt a lot from your script.