# Adding a new column to an existing csv file via Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a question. I want to add a new column to an existing filename via commands in matlab. The existing file (called 'filename1' ) has 22 columns and 400 rows. I 've created the column that I want to add, which has 400 rows too. The final output I want to have is a .csv file with 23 columns and 400 rows. I used these commands, without results:

```
M1 = [codes, name, num2cell(d1(1:end,7))].';  %transpose important 

fid = fopen('ga.csv','wt');
fprintf(fid,'%15s %.6f\n',M1{:} );

fclose(fid);
```

the `num2cell` is the new column that I want to add.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new column with header to csv Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617753/add-new-column-with-header-to-csv-matlab) or [Adding new columns to a text file on matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783802/adding-new-columns-to-a-text-file-on-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: you seem to have 3 columns in your cell array (`code`, `name`, and `d1`), but you only give 2 format specifiers to the `fprintf` command ... You should try adding a format specifier for each column. Assuming your variable `name` is a string, you could try: `fprintf(fid,'%15s %s %.6f\n',M1{:} );`

Comment: Does one of the above links worked for you ?

Comment: Actually , the main problem is that the main problem is in the command writetable, because command window shows me these:
Undefined function 'write' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
Error in writetable (line 106)
write(a,filename,varargin{:})
Error in test_v2_pro (line 103)
writetable(MI{:},'tabledata.txt')

Comment: You seem to struggle with the type of data you want to put in that text file. What are `codes`, `name` and `d1` in your code ? Could you edit the question with an example ?